# Condition on a sum in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two columns `a` and `b` and I want to select the tuples that respect the condition `a + b > 5`; I have tried this:

```
SELECT a, b FROM table WHERE (a + b) > 5;
```

but I don't obtain the result I was expecting.

Comment: What data do you have, what results do you get, and what were you expecting to see for that data?

Comment: Based on your stated requirement, that query should work just perfectly. Please post a sample of rows from your table, together with a sample of what you would expect the corresponding query output to be.

Comment: [?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13547e/1)

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of one reason that your formula would not work.  That would be the presence of `NULL` values.  Does this fix the problem?

```
select a, b
from table
where (coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0)) > 5;
```